# How to reset a flash drive murdered by dd

Tags: debian, dd

I have a 64GB flash drive onto which I've previously `dd`'ed a Debian installation. I'd like to do this again (`dd` a complete Debian install from my machine onto the flash drive) but I've run into some bizarre problems, described below:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    28G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0  20.5G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   1  57.7G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1   335M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   1   2.8M  0 part
```

The flash drive, `sdb`, is reporting a smaller size here than I know to be the case. Where are the missing 8GB? `dd` seems to find them:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
16238561+0 records in
16238560+0 records out
8314142720 bytes (8.3 GB, 7.7 GiB) copied, 16.2814 s, 511 MB/s
```

So to summarize: the flash drive `/dev/sdb` seems to be 58GB (8 smaller than it used to be) but only a few hundred MB seem to be visible in two partitions. Just writing directly to `/dev/sdb` seems to only expose 8GB.

EDIT:

`dmesg` output when removing and reinserting the drive:

```
[ 4952.579464] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 11
[ 4971.326113] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 4971.492654] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1666, bcdDevice= 1.10
[ 4971.492660] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4971.492663] usb 1-1: Product: DataTraveler 3.0
[ 4971.492666] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
[ 4971.492669] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 1831BFB81BC8B36039AB0126
[ 4971.494616] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4971.494900] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 4972.507815] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 4972.508438] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 4972.508714] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 121061376 512-byte logical blocks: (62.0 GB/57.7 GiB)
[ 4972.509130] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 4972.509134] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 00
[ 4972.509498] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
```

EDIT: to clarify, the biggest problem here is that I can no longer access 58GB of the drive. `dd` reports no space left after writing some 8GB. `lsblk` insists that that device is 58GB, but `fdisk` agrees with `dd` on the device only being 8GB.

Comment: What does `sudo dmesg` show about the drive? You can unplug it and plug it again and the last lines of `dmesg` will show all the relevant information.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani updated with that info. dmesg seems to see the full size of the drive.

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) will help you analyze the problem, and if you are lucky, solve it. The problem with the wrong size might be that the drive was sold with a **fake size**, but there might also be some kind of confusion.

Comment: did your flash drive show as 64GB when you first used it? ... there is a difference between `gigabyte`, GB, which is decimal based and `gibibyte`, GiB, which is binary based .... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte .... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte ... the sales people use one, the computer reports the other ........ 64GB == 59.60464GiB

Answer (score 2):

If it is OK to lose all data on the drive you can reset it as follows:

(1) Make sure the drive is not mounted, perhaps do:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb
```

(2) Remove everything (be sure to check the `of` field to be exactly your drive to be reset!)

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=2M count=32
```

(3) Initialise with a partition table

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
```

Inside `fdisk`, create a new partition (number 1) that covers everything, assign partition type "b".  You can do this by entering the letters/commands (after // is my comment)

```
n         // new partition
1         // partition number, if you are asked
<enter>   // Yes, from the first available sector
<enter>   // Yes, to the last one

t         // change the type of partition 1
b         // partition type: Windows 95 FAT32
p         // have a look at what you have done (print)
```

If it looks OK -- 1 partition, whole size, type "b" then

```
w         // write to disk
```

Then create a file system on the new drive `/dev/sdb1`:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1
```

That ought to do it.  Remove and re-plug the drive unless it is already automatically mounted.